# How can I reference a codebuild project from a different region in CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am using CDK to deploy a codepipeline. My design is to deploy codebuild projects to different regions and reference them in one single pipeline in one region.

I build the codebuild project as:

```js
export class CodebuildCdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  region: string;

  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
  }

  createCodebuildProject = () => {
    return new codebuild.PipelineProject(this, name, ...
    });
  }
}

const project1 = new CodebuildCdkStack(this, 'project1', {env: {region: 'ap-southeast-1', account}});

const project2 = new CodebuildCdkStack(this, 'project2', {env: {region: 'ap-southeast-2', account}});

actions1 =new actions.CodeBuildAction({
          ...
          project: codebuild.PipelineProject.fromProjectArn(this, `project1`, project1.projectArn),
});

actions2 =new actions.CodeBuildAction({
          ...
          project: codebuild.PipelineProject.fromProjectArn(this, `project2`, project2.projectArn),
});
```

When I run `cdk deploy`, I got this error:

```
The 'account' property must be a concrete value (action: 'project1')
```

After some debugging, I found the value `project1.projectArn` is not an Arn string, instead it is a Token object. So how can I reference the codebuild project in a correct way?

Comment: Possible solution: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/14741#issuecomment-844400505

Comment: What's `xxx`? How are you defining the account?

Comment: xxx is the aws account id.

Comment: @KaustubhKhavnekar the solution only works for the same region since it uses project name to import. but for cross region, it has to be arn

Comment: Is `account` the actual account id, hardcoded in there?